# How to collect I/O Bandwidth statistics on ubuntu 14.

Tags: ubuntu, shell-scripting, network-monitoring, bandwidth-measuring

I want to write script/service to collect I/O bandwidth consumption on daily basis. I know nload tool which will show total I/O data transfer from the time we executed the command. I want script to generate data for this bandwidth and save in some file on day to day or per hours basic. Please suggest if I can use any other tool.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Check out a tool like [Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/), [Zabbix](https://www.zabbix.com/), [Icinga](https://www.icinga.com/).

If you really want to collect data by hand check out `/proc/net/dev` which gives you the current transmitted/received byte and packet count among others since system boot (or driver start). Subtract the current value from a previously captured and you get how many bytes or packets have been transmitted/received since then.